# Can a Primefaces tab be manually reset to force a reload

Tags: primefaces, tabview

I'm using a Primefaces tabView with the dynamic and cache attributes set to true -
each tab is thus loaded the first time it's displayed and then cached so it does need to be reloaded.
Is there a way to manually force a reload of an already cached tab so that the next time it is displayed it's content is fetched again from the server and not from the cache?

So if I have something like

```
<p:tabView id="MyTabViewId" widgetVar="_MyTabViewId" dynamic="true" cache="true">
...
</p:tabView>
```

I could write some javascript simillar to the following

```
PF('_MyTabViewId').invalidate(0);
PF('_MyTabViewId').select(0);
```

and the first tab would be loaded from the server no matter if it's in the cache or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can simply add this script to your page...

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widget.TabView) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.TabView.prototype.reloadTab = function(index) {
        var reloadPanel = this.panelContainer.children().eq(index);
        reloadPanel.data('loaded', false);
        this.select(index);
    }
}
```

That adds a reloadPanel method to the widget so you can then do this `PF('_MyTabViewId').reloadPanel(0);`

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8007

PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/8008

Will be included in PrimeFaces 11.0.0

Comment: Thanks a lot; that worked a charm